# How to get the time in Hawaii from the OS X command line?

Tags: macos, command-line, time

As the title states, I would like to get the current time in Hawaii (UTC -10:00) from the OS X command line.  Could anyone help?

Comment: It looks like OS X uses the [tz database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database), so you might try this: `TZ="Pacific/Honolulu" date`. Works on Linux, anyway.

Comment: That is great!  Thank you.  If you post it as an answer I would be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like OS X uses the tz database, so the following should work: `TZ="Pacific/Honolulu" date`

Answer (score 2):

Sometime ago I wrote a little world clock script to easily perform exactly this kind of task. Perhaps it will be found useful.

```
#!/bin/sh

# Display date and time in different time zones/major cities.

STAT="1" # DEFAULT EXIT STATUS; RESET TO 0 BEFORE NORMAL EXIT
zoneinfo=/usr/share/zoneinfo
city_zone=$1
date_format='%a %F %T'

# Functions
timestamp() {
    date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S
}

get_date() {
    zone_date=$(TZ="$find_zone" date +"$date_format")
    printf "%-34s %23s\n" ${find_zone#$zoneinfo} "$zone_date"
}

trap 'exit "$STAT"' EXIT 0
trap 'echo "`timestamp`: Abnormal termination!" ; exit "$STAT"' SIGHUP 1 SIGINT 2 SIGQUIT 3 SIGKILL 9 SIGTERM 15

find $zoneinfo -type f | grep -i "$city_zone" | while read find_zone
    do
        get_date
    done

STAT="0"
exit "$STAT"
```

When run the output is:

```
$ ./wclock York
/America/New_York                  Tue 2014-01-14 04:14:26
$ ./wclock London
/Europe/London                     Tue 2014-01-14 09:14:48
```